# Inadequate Account Lockout in java

Tags: java, oracle, security, servlets, authentication

I have a `login page` in `jsp` where i am authenticating users by their `login id` and `passwords` in a `servlet(doPost)` but by security scan i got the following error:

```
Inadequate Account Lockout
```

how can i `enforce account lockout after several failed login attempts`?

I am using `oracle 10g EE as backend`

**EDIT**: `Login Authentication is done from database(oracle 10g ee)`

Any help please

Comment: Why are you randomly putting sentences in code tags?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put a "login_attempt" field in the User's table ? Increment the value for this column by 1 for every failed login attempt by that User.

If this number increases the threshold value(say 3), lock the account..

Comment: thanks Shashank but account lockout means will i redirect that user to a different page or any thing else i should do? Or simply i will show by a message that your account has been locked?

Comment: I think you should show a message letting user know that his account has been locked...